# I think $\phi_1, \phi_2, \dots$ are of class $C^\infty$ but their sum is not continuous. Am I right? ("Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres)

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\phi_i(x)=1$ if $x\in A$.
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\phi_i(x)=0$ if $x\notin A$.
So, I think $\phi_1, \phi_2, \dots$ are of class $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ but their sum is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
The author didn't remark this.
So, I am not sure that I am right or not.
Am I right?

> **Theorem 16.3 (Existence of a partition of unity).** Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $A$ be their union. There exists a sequence $\phi_1,\phi_2,\dots$ of continuous functions $\phi_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that:
> (1) $\phi_i(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$.
> (2) The set $S_i=\operatorname{Support}\phi_i$ is contained in $A$.
> (3) Each point of $A$ has a neighborhood that intersects only finitely many of the sets $S_i$.
> (4) $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\phi_i(x)=1$ for each $x\in A$.
> (5) The functions $\phi_i$ are of class $C^{\infty}$.
> (6) The sets $S_i$ are compact.
> (7) For each $i$, the set $S_i$ is contained in an element of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: See   condition (3), it is (in effect) a finite sum  therefore also $C^\infty$

Comment: @WillJagy $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\phi_i$ is $C^\infty$ on $A$, but I think it is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The sum-function $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \phi_i$ is not continuous (unless in the trivial cases $A =\emptyset$ and $A = \mathbb R^n$. But this is irrelevant, Munkres wants to partition unity only for the points $x \in A$. What is outside of $A$ is not interesting.

Comment: Paul Frost, Thank you very much for your answer.